# compare value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one number textbox.
And another list of textboxes. What I want is, textbox value entered should be compared for equality with the total of values entered in list.
I am facing problem as total value is return by a custom filter and is displayed in span.

Can anyone please help?

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LzYoEpmfErSQOPClTRjc?p=preview)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
  .filter('sumByKey', function () {
            return function (data, key) {
                if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
                    return 0;
                }

                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    sum += isNaN(parseInt(data[i][key])) ? 0 : parseInt(data[i][key]);
                }

                return sum;
            };
        })
  .controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter) {
    
    $scope.valueArray = [{key:1, value:1},
    {key:2, value:2},
    {key:3, value:3},
    {key:4, value:4},
    {key:5, value:5}];
    
    $scope.arrayTotal = $filter('sumByKey')($scope.valueArray,'value');
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">



<body ng-app="myReverseFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Sample Value : <input ng-model="greeting" type="number">
    <hr>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in valueArray">
        <td>{{item.key}}</td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="item.value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>{{arrayTotal}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you want?  http://plnkr.co/edit/czT1oW8pUZ2tp9kTMtWy?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jwnt98263xNgFYckeDNm?p=preview

I've made a function `$scope.match`, which checks for equality between the total and the entered variable.  I've added a `<p>` element on the page too to show the result.  I've also wrapped your `$scope.arrayTotal` variable in a function so that it updates when the above boxes are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not sure of what you wanted to achieve I devised the following two snipets, using the same filter `checkForMatch` in order to compare values.

The first snipet compares values between individual list values and the second one compares them to total sum of those values.

The filter is NOT production ready. There are a lot of issues that should be addressed with it, but for the given information, I believe it is enough.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
    .filter('sumByKey', function() {
      return function(data, key) {
        if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
          return 0;
        }

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          sum += isNaN(parseInt(data[i][key])) ? 0 : parseInt(data[i][key]);
        }

        return sum;
      };
    })
    .filter('checkForMatch', function() {
      return function(input, value, greeting) {
        if(value === greeting)
        {
          return 'Match!';
        }
        return input;
      };
    })
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter) {

      $scope.valueArray = [{
        key: 1,
        value: 1
      }, {
        key: 2,
        value: 2
      }, {
        key: 3,
        value: 3
      }, {
        key: 4,
        value: 4
      }, {
        key: 5,
        value: 5
      }];

      $scope.arrayTotal = $filter('sumByKey')($scope.valueArray, 'value');
      
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myReverseFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Sample Value : <input ng-model="greeting" type="number">
    <hr>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in valueArray">
        <td>{{item.value | checkForMatch : greeting}}</td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="item.value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>{{arrayTotal}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
    .filter('sumByKey', function() {
      return function(data, key) {
        if (typeof(data) === 'undefined' || typeof(key) === 'undefined') {
          return 0;
        }

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          sum += isNaN(parseInt(data[i][key])) ? 0 : parseInt(data[i][key]);
        }

        return sum;
      };
    })
    .filter('checkForMatch', function() {
      return function(input, greeting) {
        if(input === greeting)
        {
          return 'Match!';
        }
        return input;
      };
    })
    .controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter) {

      $scope.valueArray = [{
        key: 1,
        value: 1
      }, {
        key: 2,
        value: 2
      }, {
        key: 3,
        value: 3
      }, {
        key: 4,
        value: 4
      }, {
        key: 5,
        value: 5
      }];

      $scope.arrayTotal = $filter('sumByKey')($scope.valueArray, 'value');
      
    });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myReverseFilterApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Sample Value : <input ng-model="greeting" type="number">
    <hr>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in valueArray">
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="item.value" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>{{arrayTotal | checkForMatch : greeting}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```